# Error bars look huge in R, but not in Excel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having an issue with my error bars. they look gigantic in R, but look much more accurate in Excel. Example in R:[image]

Example in Excel:[image]

### Code

```
Graph = subset(dat,dat$Condition != "z" & dat$Environment != "a") 
    Graph %>%
      group_by(Gate = fct_inorder(Gate), Sound, Block) %>%
      summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct), 
                sd = sd(Correct)) %>%    
      ggplot(aes(x = Gate, y = Accuracy, color = Sound, group = Sound)) + 
      geom_line() + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - sd, ymax = Accuracy + sd,)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
      facet_wrap(~Block) + 
      theme_minimal()
```

### Reproducible sample

```
        set.seed(42)
    n <- 100
    dat <- data.frame(Participant=1:n, 
                      Environment=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                      Condition=rep(LETTERS[25:26], n/2),
                      Gate= sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
                      Block= sample(1:2,n, replace=TRUE),
                      Sound=rep(LETTERS[3:4], n/2),
                      Correct=sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)
)
```

Comment: Both Excel and ggplot will plot the data you give it. Don't focus on the plotting - focus on the data. Stop your data pipeline after the `summarize()` line and see if it looks right.

Comment: Not a big deal, but you're missing a closing parenthesis in creating that data frame. I wouldn't assume one method is more accurate than the other; ggplot presented the values you gave it. If those are incorrect, it's because you gave it the wrong values, not something inherent to R. Your sample data is also missing `Block`. There also isn't any reason given why you would expect SDs to be any different

Comment: I think you are looking for the standard error of the mean rather than the standard deviation. Change `sd(Correct)` to `sd(Correct)/sqrt(length(Correct))`

Comment: @AllanCameron, please post as answer ...

Comment: @AllanCameron That did it! sorry, I am a noob here on SO. how can I format them to a smaller thickness/size now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer points out, you should be looking at the standard error (`sd/sqrt(n)`) rather than the standard deviation. Here is  a slightly more compact way to run your code, using `stat_summary()` to compute the summary statistics (`mean_cl_normal` normally plots the Normal 95% CIs, `mult = 1` tells it to plot ±1 SE instead).  If you want the end-caps on your error bars to be narrower, use the `width=` argument to adjust them.

(My plot still has large error bars but I assume that's because of the size of your reproducible example.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
filter(dat, Condition != "z" & Environment != "a") %>%
  mutate(across(Gate = fct_inorder)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Gate, Correct, colour = Sound)) +
  stat_summary(geom="line", fun = mean) +
  stat_summary(geom="errorbar", fun.data = \(x) mean_cl_normal(x, mult=1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Block)
```

Answer (score 2):

They look huge because I was calculating standard deviation instead of standard error. In the above code, I changed

```
sd(Correct)
```

to

```
sd(Correct)/sqrt(length(Correct))
```